HTML/CSS: Issue with textbox border color
I'm just learning to write html/css and I'm trying to create a copy of the Google search page.
I'm having issues with my textbox's border color as half is black and the other half is grey.
Why is this happening and how do I change the entire textbox's border color to light grey?
Sorry, I'm a newbie and this might be a dumb question but I appreciate your input! Thank you in advance!
Here's my html/css code and html page:
(https://i.sstatic.net/WiDYpb3w.png)


.logo {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.search {
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(159, 159, 159);
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgb(202, 202, 202);
}
<img class="logo" src="mothers-day-2024-may-12-6753651837110364-ldrk.png">
<input class="search" type="textbox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">



I've tried changing the border-color but half is always black.

By default, input element has border-style set to inset and what you are asking for is solid style. To overwrite that, add a CSS rule inside selector .search with property border-style set to value solid
After adding the said rule, your code will look like this:


.logo {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.search {
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(159, 159, 159);
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgb(202, 202, 202);
  border-style: solid;
  /* added rule */
}
<img class="logo" src="mothers-day-2024-may-12-6753651837110364-ldrk.png">
<input class="search" type="textbox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">




Use border: 1px solid red instead of specifying border-color: rgb(159, 159, 159).


      .logo{
        margin-left: 70px;
      }
      .search{
        width: 600px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgb(202, 202, 202);
      }
  <img class="logo" src="mothers-day-2024-may-12-6753651837110364-ldrk.png">
  <input class="search" type="textbox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">




I don't know why you're using padding-top and padding-bottom separately even though they have the same value. I rewrite the code please check this one.


.logo {
        margin-left: 70px;
      }
      .search {
        width: 600px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(159, 159, 159);
        font-size: 20px;
        box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgb(202, 202, 202);
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="logo" src="mothers-day-2024-may-12-6753651837110364-ldrk.png" />
    <input
      class="search"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search Google or type a URL"
    />
  </body>
</html>



